# HiDPI in IntelliJ 13.1, how to use it? what is it good for?

Tags: intellij-idea, highdpi

I've just seen that there is [HiDPI support](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP) for Windows in IDEA 13.1 :

> Support Windows/Linux HiDPI devices via -Dis.hidpi=true

What does this mean exactly ? How can I enable it ? Where should I set this flag ?

I have a high resolution monitor and having higher DPI fonts would be nice, will this setting help with that ? If yes, how can I take advantage of that ?

Answer (score 10):

I've discovered that using checking "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" in compatibility tab of the Intellij executable or shortcut does the job!
I had to reinstall from scratch before it worked.

Answer (score 10):

1. Right click on intellij shortcut icon
2. properties
3. compatibility tab
4. check -> disable display scaling

Notice you get a bit smaller icons. Of course then you need to re-size font of code.

Answer (score 6):

I am using PyCharm and had the same problem.

1. I edited the `pycharm.exe.vmoptions` file in the PyCharm programs folder (make sure you open notepad as administrator)
2. added the line `-Dis.hidpi=true` - saved the file.
3. right clicked on the pycharm.exe file and ticked DPI scaling
4. started PyCharm
5. in the general appearance preferences scaled the font up to 20 (I have a 4k display)
6. in Editor > [mouse] ticked change font size with scroll mouse
7. increased editor font by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll up on mouse.

Not it looks beautiful compared to the horrible jaggy fonts that make you wish that you had never seen the grass in high resolution!

Answer (score 3):

Think it goes to **idea.exe.vmoptions** as per http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/04/configuring-intellij-idea-vm-options/#comment-85

I must say on a Surface Pro the difference was barely noticeable - font weight in code editing window is marginally **bolder**.

Comment: For Linux, the right file to put it in seems to be <installation directory>/bin/idea.properties or <installation directory>/bin/idea64.vmoptions (64 bits systems).

Comment: The odd thing is that one still needs to pump-up the font-size. Why is this? (in KDE & Fireforx/Thunderbird I only need to indicate that the DPI is higher)

Answer (score 3):

For **surface 3 pro**, the following worked a lot better for me - with no required changes to font's or other such settings.

```
-Dhidpi=true
```

*-Dis.hidpi=true* 
did not work so well for me.

Answer (score 2):

The JetBrains team works on support of HiDPI in IntelliJ on Windows. There's an early access version: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP (text is still blur on my computer, but maybe you'll have more luck).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `-Dhidpi=true` in `[your_ide_here].vmoptions` file works on Linux as well (and with PhpStorm 9), as also stated on Arch Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#IntelliJ_IDEA.

Also, overriding default fonts in Appearance settings prevents HiDPI support from working in some GUI elements.

Answer (score 1):

Newly released [IntelliJ IDEA 15](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#evenMore) has true HiDPI support for Windows and Linux. It works perfectly for me.